# Why does NVMe naming always changed randomly in Ubuntu 22.04 after system reboot?

Tags: 22.04, nvme, naming

Procedure:

1. Install NVMe SSD*16 to SUT.
2. Power on SUT.
3. Into OS and type "nvme list"

   ```
   Node                  SN                   Model                                   
   --------------------- -------------------- -------------------------------------
   /dev/nvme9n1          S796NG0W800021       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07           
   /dev/nvme8n1          S796NG0W800042       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07           
   /dev/nvme7n1          S796NG0W800014       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07             
   /dev/nvme6n1          S796NG0W800053       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07             
   /dev/nvme5n1          S796NG0W800070       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07               
   /dev/nvme4n1          S796NG0W800071       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07              
   /dev/nvme3n1          S796NG0W800016       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07               
   /dev/nvme2n1          S796NG0W800015       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07             
   /dev/nvme15n1         S796NG0W800019       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07              
   /dev/nvme14n1         S796NG0W800031       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07              
   /dev/nvme13n1         S796NG0W800027       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07            
   /dev/nvme12n1         S796NG0W800034       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07             
   /dev/nvme11n1         S796NG0W800068       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07             
   /dev/nvme10n1         S796NG0W800066       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07           
   /dev/nvme1n1          S796NG0W800018       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07              
   /dev/nvme0n1          S796NG0W800011       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07
   ```
4. Set system to reboot.
5. Into OS and type "nvme list"

   ```
   Node                  SN                   Model                                    
   --------------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------
   /dev/nvme9n1          S796NG0W800011       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07               
   /dev/nvme8n1          S796NG0W800042       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07              
   /dev/nvme7n1          S796NG0W800031       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07             
   /dev/nvme6n1          S796NG0W800070       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07             
   /dev/nvme5n1          S796NG0W800019       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07             
   /dev/nvme4n1          S796NG0W800021       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07            
   /dev/nvme3n1          S796NG0W800053       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07           
   /dev/nvme2n1          S796NG0W800014       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07          
   /dev/nvme15n1         S796NG0W800018       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07             
   /dev/nvme14n1         S796NG0W800066       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07              
   /dev/nvme13n1         S796NG0W800015       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07              
   /dev/nvme12n1         S796NG0W800016       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07           
   /dev/nvme11n1         S796NG0W800068       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07             
   /dev/nvme10n1         S796NG0W800034       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07           
   /dev/nvme1n1          S796NG0W800027       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07            
   /dev/nvme0n1          S796NG0W800071       SAMSUNG MZWLO7T6HBLA-00A07
   ```

Config:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Linux 6.2.0-39-generic)

Isolation:
This issue doesn't occur in RHEL v9.2.

Comment: Devices are named based on the order they announce themselves to the OS. This can change from boot to boot depending on the state of the devices being queried and the power delivery from the board.

Comment: does [this Stack Exchange Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288872/change-name-of-mounted-hard-drive) help in understanding how to persistently name the device in fstab?

Comment: I also suffer from device name changes, so I mount based on UUID: `sudo mount -t ext4 UUID=0ac356c1-caa9-4c2e-8229-4408bd998dbd /media/nvme`